# Log4J2 main arguments in configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, program-entry-point, log4j2

I am trying to access main arguments from xml config file of log4j2.
It works if i use index based arguments, but when i switch to name based arguments `${main:--file}` it stops working.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have found a bug. Please raise a ticket on the log4j2 [Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2).